# Nesting routes throws an undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I have two resources - users and lists, which I want to nest. Everything worked fine, but as soon as i nest lists in users, it throws en error. It works fine on localhost - its just the tests that fails.

This is one of the errors:

```
  1) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `lists_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fecbd7812f0>:0x007fecbad265a0>
     # ./app/views/shared/_create_list.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_shared__create_list_html_erb___4033534818329635871_70327383327980'
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___4510442023060893439_70327361676640'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:7:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

routs.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :lists, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :items, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 60 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :lists
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my paths in my app. Instead of `list_path(list)`, it has to be `user_list_path(user, list)`